# KDE: Disable password prompt after resume

Tags: kde

I'm running KDE on Fedora Workstation 21.

When I wake up my machine after suspending it, it always prompts for my password.

If there any way to disable this? I've looked through the settings but can't see how this is done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Power management -> advanced settings -> Lock screen on resume.

EDIT: In later Plasma vesrions, it's in

System settings -> Desktop Behaviour -> Screen locking.

In even later versions:

System settings -> Workspace Behaviour -> Screen locking.

Quick tip:
In the systemsettings screen, there is an useful dialong in which you can search for "lock", it'll highlight the relevant icons.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: I found Power Management as a tab within "Monitor & Display" but it doesn't have advanced settings.

Comment: @user829755  Plasma has changed wuite a lot in the last year. I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update. I still can't find it here, but that's probably due to my Trinity Desktop Environment. TDE has System Settings > Desktop > Screen Saver > Require password to stop but that's not related to suspend/resume.

Comment: @user829755 Trinity is a fork of KDE3. Two versions old. It's just a completely different thing, it is *not* KDE. Please do not confuse possible readers by mixing the two.

Answer (score -1):

TDEpowersave does it on this laptop. Locate its icon on the panel, it looks like a power plug with a battery bar beside it. Right-click, select settings, and look for something like "screen lock" (sorry, can't guess the exact English wording, an i18n version here.) Disable it. Did the trick for me.

Comment: I'd say this question is to with KDE4 / plasma, not a feature of the Trinity fork (TDE), which google suggests is only available for Fedora as a third-party repo.

Comment: You are very welcome to document what solved your own problem, as a separate question - the site allows and deliberately supports answering your own question - there is a feature that lets you post both at once.

Comment: When you have more reputation, you would be able to add a comment in direct response to the one by user829755, to point to the more appropriate question.